# What's the most Pythonic/Django-y way to store long string assets?

Tags: python, django, string, django-templates

I have a function in my Django app that has a dictionary containing several long strings. When that function is called, those strings are formatted and the dictionary returned.

For example:

```
def my_strings(foo, bar, baz):
    return = {
        'string1': 'a really long string! %s' % foo,
        'string2': 'another long one. %s %s' % (foo, bar),
        'string3': 'yet another! %s %s %s' % (foo, bar, baz),
    }
```

However, having all these long strings, stored in a Python file is ugly and it seems there should be a cleaner way to do it.

I'd toyed with putting them in a template file and doing some rendering, like so:

**mytemplate.txt**

```
{% if string1 %}
a really long string! {{ foo }}
{% endif %}

{% if string2 %}
another long one. {{ foo }} {{ bar }}
{% endif %}

{% if string3 %}
yet another! {{ foo }} {{ bar }} {{ baz }}
{% endif %}
```

**Python**

```
def my_strings(foo, bar, baz):
    arg_dict = {
        'foo': foo,
        'bar': bar,
        'baz': baz,
    }

    my_strings = {}
    string_names = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']

    for s in string_names:
        arg_dict[s] = True
        my_strings[s] = render_to_string('mytemplate.txt', arg_dict).strip()
        del arg_dict[s]

    return my_strings
```

But that seems a little too roundabout, and most likely less performant.

Is there a preferred way in Python, or Django specifically, to handle storing and formatting long string assets?

Some extra context: the string assets are either HTML or plaintext. The dictionary is eventually iterated over and all instances of each key in yet another string are replaced with its string value.

Comment: Aside: you can use dictionary substitution: `"word is %(x)s"%{"x": "this"}`

Comment: hayden: I actually do use `%(x)s` format. I just simplified it for the sake of asking the question. :)

Comment: That do not look like a better way, but it is an approach anyway... You can [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) the resulting dictionary and stora it in a file, or on cache or in database. Uding a dictionary substitution is the best way for this approach. But as i said, it is one of the approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would treat this as something similar to the way many i8n compilation code does it.

Store the long strings in a dictionary in a separate file. Import that dictionary and then format the desired string in your code.

Comment: Good call. I hadn't thought of how similar this is to the way i8n code works, but that's pretty much spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the strings in a module like longstrings.py

```
STRING1 = ("Bla bla"
     " more text"
     " even more text")

STRING2 = ("Bla bla"
     " more text"
     " even more text")
```

and then

```
from  longstrings import *

def my_strings(foo, bar, baz):
    return = {
        'string1': STRING1 % foo,
        'string2': STRING2 % (foo, bar),
        'string3': STRING2 % (foo, bar, baz),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a class for your long strings, and they would be stored in the DB.  This would allow you to access them and modify them as any other object.  For example, you could use the Django admin tool if you want to modify a specific string.